# Get data from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```sql
Select 
   Id, 
   ROW_NUMBER() over(Order By(Select 1)) as SNo,  
   Tableno as 'Table Number',  
   convert(Date, tableorder.Date) as Date,  
   (LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), tableorder.Date, 100), 7))) as Time,  
   case 
       when TableOrder.Status = 1 then 'Open' 
       when TableOrder.Status = 0  then 'Close'
       else 'Undifined'
   end As 'Order Status', 
   KotNO as 'Kot Number', 
   (Select SUM(NetAmount) 
    from Bill 
    where Bill.OrderId = TableOrder.Id) as 'Total  Amount' 
from 
    TableOrder 
Where 
    IsActive = '1' And IsDelete = '0'
```

This query returns this data:

```
Id  SNo  Table Number  Date        Time     Order Status  Kot Number  Total  Amount
318 1    1             4/3/2013    12:00AM  Close         1218        270
319 2    1             4/3/2013    12:00AM  Close         7581        335
320 3    1             4/3/2013    12:00AM  Close         7582        110
321 4    1             4/3/2013    12:00AM  Close         7585        165
323 5    4             4/3/2013    12:00AM  Close         7586        80
324 6    1             4/3/2013    12:00AM  Close         7587        45
325 7    3             4/3/2013    12:00AM  Close         7588        150
326 8    1             4/3/2013    12:00AM  Close         7589        145
327 9    1             4/3/2013    12:00AM  Close         7590        70
328 10   4             4/3/2013    12:00AM  Close         7591        120
```

I want to add 2 columns in this query for Vat 5% rate Amount = vat type id 2 and Vat 15% rate Amount = vat Type id 4

I have a second query like this in this query I use TableOrder id = 319

```sql
Select 
    Vt.Id, Vt.Description,
    abs(Vt.Rate) as VRate,
    Sum((( ItemPrice * Qty) - NetAmount)) as VatAmount 
from 
    BillItem1 as B1 
Left JOIN 
    ItemDescription ItD ON ItD.Id = B1.itemId 
Left Join 
    VatType Vt on Vt.Id = ItD.TaxId 
where 
    B1.IsActive = 1 and B1.IsDelete = 0 
    and B1.OrderId = 319 
Group By 
    Vt.Id, Vt.Rate, Vt.Description 
Order By 
    SUM((ItemPrice*Qty) - NetAmount) DESC
```

Output:

```
Id  Description  VRate  VatAmount
2   Food         5      8.8094
4   Cold drinks  15     7.143
```

In this query get vat 5%  for Vat type Id = 2 and 15 % for Vat type Id = 4  in above data 390 TableOrder Id Show Total Amount 270 and Vat Amount is (8.8094+7.143)

I want this amount show in below data in column

Table relation is

In Table BillItem Table I have Item Id and TableOrder Id
In Item Table I have VatTypeId

Comment: reduce the length of your question.

Comment: Please format the question.

Comment: Did someone mark him down because he hadn't formatted the question correctly? Shame on you if you did - he's new to the site and probably doesn't know how to do it properly yet.

Comment: @Jack How do you mean that you want to 'show in below data in column'? Do you mean in the right most column?

Comment: I want to first column for 5%vat amount and second column for 15%vat amount.
See first query data, here id = 319
and this 319 id have a two vat type, Both are avaible in 2nd query output. How to show  in 2nd query data only vat amount 5% & 15% in 1st query data output.

Comment: Have you got `TableOrder.Date` as a `NVARCHAR` or similar?  It shouild really be a `DateTime`...

Comment: @Westie grumpy people exist everywhere. I have been docked for all kinds of things, and sadly the down voters will not even bother answering the question but will put all their energy into downvoting and defending their downvote.

Comment: @Jack - did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're after.  Try the following...

```sql
SELECT
    Id, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) as SNo,  
    Tableno AS 'Table Number',  
    convert(DateTime, tableorder.Date) AS [Date],  
    (LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), tableorder.Date, 100), 7))) as [Time],  
    CASE
        WHEN TableOrder.Status = 1 THEN 'Open' 
        WHEN TableOrder.Status = 0 THEN 'Close'
        ELSE 'Undefined'
    END AS 'Order Status', 
    KotNO AS 'Kot Number', 
    SUM(Bill.NetAmount) AS 'Total Amount', 
    SUM(Bill.NetAmount) * 0.05 AS 'Tax 5', 
    SUM(Bill.NetAmount) * 0.15 AS 'Tax 15' 

FROM
    TableOrder INNER JOIN 
    Bill 
        ON TableOrder.Id = Bill.OrderId 

WHERE 
    IsActive = '1' And 
    IsDelete = '0' 

GROUP BY 
    Id, 
    Tableno,  
    TableOrder.[Date],  
    TableOrder.Status, 
    KotNO
```

See how that works for you.